# Uniform Convergence of the series on the closed interval

Tags: real-analysis

a). Let $f_n(x) =  {x^2\over (1+x^2)^n}$ for $x\in \mathbb R$. Evaluate $\sum_{n=0} ^\infty f_n(x)$.

b). For which values does this series converges uniformly on $[a,b]$?

My attempt: for a). I have $\sum_{n=0} ^\infty f_n(x) = x^2 +1 $ when ${1\over |x^2+1|} < 1.$

b). I got stuck at b). I don't really understand the question. I can show that series is uniform convergent by using M-test but I don't know how to show it is uniformly continuous on the interval.

Helps are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea for (a) is correct. Note that $\frac{1}{|x^2+1|}<1$ is equivalent to $x\neq0$, since $x^2+1>1$ iff $x\neq0$.

For (b) note that the series only has a chance to converge uniformly, if it converges pointwise, and from (a) we now know that this is the case iff $x\neq0$. That means that $0\notin[a,b]$ which gives two cases: (i) $0<a<b$ and (ii) $a<b<0$.

For case (i) we can use the $M$-test, i.e. if $x\in[a,b]$ and $0<a<b$, then
\begin{align*}
|f_n(x)|=\frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^n}\leq \frac{b^2}{(a^2+1)^n},
\end{align*}
and since the (geomeric) series
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{b^2}{(a^2+1)^n}
\end{align*}
converges, the $M$-test tells us that the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)$ converges uniformly in $[a,b]$. Case (ii) is similar. Just interchange $a$ and $b$.

In summary, the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)$ converges uniformly in $[a,b]$, if and only if $0\notin[a,b]$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It is so clear now. So for case (2) I will just need to show $$\begin{align*}
|f_n(x)|=\frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^n}\leq \frac{a^2}{(b^2+1)^n},
\end{align*}$$. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes. Thanks! You are very welcome.